# sharepoint 2013 time outs after 100 seconds

Tags: sharepoint

recently we migrated from 2010 to 2013. we have some custom solutions which were fine in 2010,but after the upgrade we are experiencing a blank screen  after 100 seconds of items inserts/updates/deletes to a list. in the code the time out value is defined as 500 seconds ,and also db connection time out, Internet Information Service application pools/webs /services limits are set to 600seconds. ca configs of the web part security validation is 30 minutes. we don't know what else to check.

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting in the Web.Config which may be affecting your timeout issue.
By default the execution timeout is 110 seconds.  We have it set here for 1000 seconds.
The requestValidationMode attribute sets a version number that indicates which ASP.NET version-specific approach to validation will be used.  We've chosen the 2.0 approach.

It resides under `<system.web>`

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="1000" maxRequestLength="51200" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```